# Reference book for quadratic equations with hard exercises?

Tags: reference-request, quadratics, book-recommendation

I'm teaching advanced level mathematics. And I need good question banks on quadratic equations . More likely good question bank on advanced level maths.

Comment: This seems to be a subject of mathematics in school. Typical problems are looking for roots, drawing the graph and solving optimization problems without derivatives. There should exist a lot of school books on this.

Comment: Refer higher algebra by bernard and child